# Does Android wear watch support NFC

Tags: nfc, wear-os

I'd like to be able to scan a NFC tag from a android watch but i dont see any NFC or android beam settings in the watch emulator.  is it not supported from the watch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is currently not supported.